# jQuery e.target bubbling best practice?

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

In my heavy-ajax code, i always bind "click" the body tag & act depending on `$(e.target)` & using `$.fn.hasClass()`. However when i click on an anchor that has a `</span>` tag inside, my `$(e.target)` equals this node, and not the parent anchor as i would like it to.

From now on, i have used this trick (`var $t = $(e.target);`) :

```
/** bubbling **/
if($t.get(0).tagName !== "A" && $t.get(0).tagName !== "AREA") {
    $t = $t.parent("a");
   if(empty($t)) return true;
   //else console.log("$t.bubble()", $t);
}
```

It feels wrong somehow... Do you have any better implementation ?

---

`$.fn.live()` does not solve my issue as it still returns the span as the target. Moreover i'm looking for speed (running on atom-based touch devices) & live appeared to be way slower (twice) : http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-click/3

---

In fact, as @Guffa pointed, using `$.fn.live()` solves the span bubbling issue as i don't need the `event.target` anymore. I guess there is no other "right" answer here (using bind on a container).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the `live` method that does it for you?

```
$('a.someclass').live('click', function(){
  // do something
});
```

The `live` method binds to the body element and checks the event target against the selector.

[jQuery: live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: I need lowest overhead (running on atom-based touch devices) & live appeared to be way slower (twice) : http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-click/3

Comment: Moreover it doesn't solve my issue : the span bubbling to anchor issue.

Comment: @olouv: If you use the `live` method you don't need to use the event target, it will call different functions depending on the selector you used to register it.

Comment: @olouv, if you're that concerned about speed, the initial call to `$('a.someclass')` may be expensive and can be avoided when using event delegation (if jQuery could predict that this call is only being used to register a selector, it would skip the lookup but it can't). If you're using jQuery 1.4.x, you can use `delegate` instead, using a less expensive selector to start with (eg. `$(document).delegate('a.someclass', 'click', handler);`).

Comment: @Guffa `delegate` clearly seems to be the way to go. I'm using it instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is useful here (though other methods — `live` and `delegate` — are described below):

```
$t = $t.closest('a');
```

That starts with `$t` and works upward through the chain of parent elements until it finds one matching the given selector — "a" in this case.

Here's a rudimentary example:

HTML:

```
<a href='#'><span>Outer span <span>inner span <em>em</em></span></span></a>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var $t = $(e.target).closest('a');
    $t.css("border", "1px solid black");
    return false;
  });

});​
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ojoxu3/2)

Clicking the link puts a border around the link, whether you click in one of the spans or the `em` element or wherever.

Somewhat off-topic, but recent versions of jQuery handle this for you via [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (which basically does what you do, hooks an event on the body and then looks to see what actual element it happened on, applying a selector to element matching) and [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (same as `live` but rooted in a specific element instead of the document itself).

Comment: closest might be useful here but off-topic (don't need it in fact), live is another slower approach & i'm all about speed.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're doing this because [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) does not work on content inserted after an AJAX call. I would recommend you use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to attach your events and allow jQuery to handle this.